# CSS sticky footer with header outside the page wrap

Tags: css, html, header, sticky-footer

All the sticky footers require that you place all the content within a page-wrap except for the footer. I have a situation where the header must reside outside the page-wrap:

```
<div id="header">...</div>
<div id="page-wrap">...</div>
<div id="footer">...</div>
```

Anyone know what the addendum to the CSS would be in this case?

Comment: Can you explain what is it that you're trying to do that **requires** header outside of wrapper?

Comment: What is your `page-wrap` CSS looking like now? It's just a tweak on that really.

Comment: Why does your header need to be outside your page-wrap? I'm sure there is another way to accomplish your goal with header within page-wrap.

Comment: Such as a Wordpress theme, where `get_header()` will require the header.php. However this php usually includes `<head>` as well. Editing this can take sometime to do.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't something like the following work?

```
<div id="page-wrap">
  <div id="header">Header stuff</div>
  <div id="contents">Actual page innards</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer text</div>
```

You didn't give much detail, but I'm guessing that you want some sort of formatting to not apply to #header. The solution is to put that formatting on #contents, not #page-wrap. In fact, don't put any formatting on #page-wrap other than what is required to push the footer down.

Answer (score 0):

I used a second wrapper class to make a sticky header and footer.  While the sticky header will work fine inside the wrapper there are lots of proposed solutions to the footer not sticking.

I found some of these workarounds were causing the header issues.  After trying many of the suggested workarounds I found sticking both in their own class wrapper with the exact same properties as the original wrapper makes both sticky with the rest of the page while requiring minimal code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/virendrachandak/cF2Fv/show/)

sticky header and footer can be easily done using the CSS property position:fixed.